# Radio buttons don't save the value to the class Blazor component

Tags: .net, blazor, radio-button, blazor-webassembly, web-development-server

i made a form with inputSelects,Inputexts and InputCheckboxes the radio buttons is the only component giving me problems, i tried changing the type to int,bool and string but it dosen't change anything.
also i tried using @onchange and @oninput on other components either, maybe there's a bug somewhere. i'm using .NET 8.0, and blazor bootstrap 1.10.5

i tried with two types code, this is the first method:
with the first method i tried getting the value with a js function document.querySelector("[name='alternanzaAziendale']:checked").value and it showed the value, instead with blazor after submitting the value student.AlternanzaAziendale is empty:

```
<EditForm Model="@student" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="Students" id="studentsForm">
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="student.AlternanzaAziendale" name="alternanzaAziendale">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<InputRadio Value="1"  class="form-check-input" name="alternanzaAziendale" id="alternanzaAziendale1"/>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
 <InputRadio Value="0"  class="form-check-input" name="alternanzaAziendale"         id="alternanzaAziendale2" />
</div>
</InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm>
```

second method:

```
<EditForm Model="@student" OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="Students" id="studentsForm">
<div class="right-side">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input @onchange="@(()=> student.EsteroFamiglia = "1")" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TempoEsteroFamiglia" id="TempoEsteroFamigliaY" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input @onchange="@(()=> student.EsteroFamiglia = "0")" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TempoEsteroFamiglia" id="TempoEsteroFamigliaN" >
            </div>
        </div>
</EditForm>
```

this is the student class code

```
public class Student
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleziona se hai fatto alternanza in azienda")]
    public string AlternanzaAziendale { get; set; }

    public string TempoEsteroFamiglia { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a MRE based on your code that works as it's supposed to.  I can't see where your problem is, but it's probably in code your aren't showing.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="_model.Selected">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <InputRadio Value="1" class="form-check-input"/>
            <label class="form-check-label">
                One
            </label>

        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <InputRadio Value="2" class="form-check-input" />
            <label class="form-check-label">
                Two
            </label>
        </div>
    </InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>
        Selected: @_model.Selected
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Model _model = new();
    private EditContext? _editContext;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Get the model from the data pipeline
        _model = new();
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i found the problem, i used the Name attribute in the InputRadioGroup and Input radio, that's why it didn't worked